# Prevent SQL Developer opening table design on click

Tags: sqldeveloper

I'm using [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) 4.1.5.21 (under Windows 7 Professional 64 bit).
*(I've just downloaded latest version (17.3) and the issue is still the same.)*

Whenever I click or select a table name in the left pane it opens immediately.
How can I prevent this behaviour and be able to just select a table without triggering anything?

I've tried looking in settings, but couldn't solve it myself.

### Detailed description of the issue

[image]

Whenever I try to drag and drop a table from the left column (e.g. `STCO_BOHU`) to the query builder, it opens the table as a new tab (next to "start page" and "AllTAbles.sql")

I need to activate my query again, and only the second attempt to drag works (this is consistent, always the second one works).

Comment: Wow, this is worth a lot to you huh!! Could you add a screen shot and point out the area that pops up and what you click on to make this happen? I think it'd be helpful to those that may be able to help that don't know it with a simple addition of a visual with a couple pointing arrows and a box around the specific items if you know what I'm saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to *Tools* → *Preferences* → *Database* → *Object Viewer* and disable *Open Object on Single Click*.